# KiCad question: how to assign pins to pads when the footprint and device have different numbers of pins?

Tags: pcb, kicad

I have a vacuum tube that has 9 pins. 3 of the pins are heaters and aren't connected to the PCB I'm designing, meaning only 6 pins need to be connected to the PCB. The Tube itself sits in a panel mounted socket that's not part of the PCB.

I'd like to use a 6 position screw terminal block on the PCB to run wires to the tube socket.

I assigned a 6 position screw terminal block footprint to the tube in the schematic, but only 3 of the pins are showing as being connected in the PCB editor.

How do I assign the tube pins 6,7,8 to the footprint pins 4,5,6?

## EDIT

Adding some pictures:

So here is Unit A and Unit B of the tube on my schematic. Notice I only use pins 1,2,3 and 6,7,8. I actually lied in my first post, pins 2 and 7 aren't connected to the PCB either, so really I only need a 4 position terminal block, but the question still is the same...

[image]

I assigned a 6 pin terminal block as the footprint. In the PCB editor this is what I see. Instead, I want all the pins of the terminal block being used:

[image]

Thank you!!

Comment: What were pins 4, 5 and 6 connected to in the schematic you drew?

Comment: So the schematic symbol has 3 units, two triodes and a heater... I don't have the heater unit on my schematic

Comment: Sorry but that answer does not tally with my comment/question and my reading of your question.

Comment: No worries, i'll add some pictures to the original post to help out

Comment: You need to design your own footprint with the pin numbers corresponding to the existing tube symbol, *or* your own library symbol for the tube, with the pin numbers corresponding to the existing footprint. This means create your own footprint library, or your own schematic component library. That's a process with lots of clicks, but not actually difficult (you can easily create new footprints/parts from existing ones).

Comment: Thanks @dim that worked perfectly. Can you put that as an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to design either:

- your own footprint with the pin numbers corresponding to the existing tube symbol,
- or your own library symbol for the tube, with the pin numbers corresponding to the existing footprint.

This means create your own footprint library, or your own schematic component library. That's a process with lots of clicks, but not actually difficult (you can easily create new footprints/parts from existing ones).

Answer (score 2):

The schematic represents the *physical* components and wiring on the pcb, so it should only show those things which are actually on it.

In your design the tube is off-board, so it should not be part of your pcb schematic. However you do have a 6 position screw terminal block which connects to it, so you could create a part which has the symbol of an ECC81 (minus heater elements) and the footprint of a 6 position terminal block. You could also make one side of each triode open or a dotted line, so you can see that they are actually inside the same envelope (otherwise it looks like they are two separate tubes).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Most guitar amp designs aren't marked like that, but it could be nice. It looks like the solution is to keep the schematic as is, but create a new footprint from the screw block with different pad numbers.